# When applying for 60 day tourist visa via Thailand embassy in UK do I need to pay for children under 14?

Tags: visas, children, thailand, lithuanian-citizens

I am Lithuanian who lives in UK and Is planning to go with family of 4 on a prolonged journey to SE Asia.

I realized that Visa-On-Arrival might be not the best option (since I come from one of 'lesser' countries Lithuania), [and I could only get 15 day visa and then extend it for another 7 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81303/how-strongly-is-the-requirement-to-have-return-tickets-when-getting-a-visa-on-ar#comment-187315) (I planed to stay for 60 days and then extend it for another 30).

After looking through my options cheapest one so far seems to be to get visa directly from [Thai embassy in London (60 days visa for £25 + £10 postage)](http://thaiembassyuk.org.uk/?q=node/76). However normally one does not need to pay for Visa-On-Arrival for children under 14.

**Would I need to pay for children's visas (I have 2) when applying via Thai Embassy in UK?**

Comment: The UK Thai embassy website makes no mention of special pricing for minors, nor does the US Thai embassy site; this makes me believe that there is no such special pricing.

Comment: I tried calling Thai embassy in London on +442075892944 and get through to operator (option 0) but after 28 minute wait they connected and immediately hang up on me  (you should have seen my face....)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a confirmation:

My visas arrived today and they indeed billed everyone 25GBP, they even included receipt per person....

This totaled: ((`£25` (visa fee) + `£10` (fee to throw our passports back into postage box)) x 1.125 (postal order that is the only way to pay fee 12.5% on sum sent) + `£6` prepaid envelope) x 4 (persons) = (`£39.375 + £6`) x 4 = `£181.5`

Note: Although it is required to send prepaid envelope per person they have sent all 4 passports in one prepaid envelope back... So maybe sending just one prepaid envelope could suffice...

Comment: Dealing with other government agencies, I have found that they insist on separate envelopes for each passport.  It makes things more convenient if they must delay one of the passports, and cost them nothing.