# Must I have return or onward tickets when getting a visa-on-arrival Cambodia (Phnom Penh)?

Tags: airlines, regulations, cambodia, proof-of-onward-travel, lithuanian-citizens

We are travelling as a family of four. Our passports are European (Lithuanian).

I was planning on flying one way and then staying until 'I had enough' of Cambodia (maybe 6 months maybe more) and then head for Laos or Vietnam. Plan is to get Visas on Arrival (E), and then extend them for 3-6 months...

Cambodian [immigration website](http://www.embassyofcambodia.org/faq.html) does list onward tickets as requirement and,
I [recently had a 'revelation'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81303/how-strongly-is-the-requirement-to-have-return-tickets-when-getting-a-visa-on-ar) that I need to have return or onward tickets in most countries, (I have been checked for visas and fly-onward tickets when boarding EVA Air in Heathrow)...

> - A completed visa application form
> - A Passport with at least 6 months validity
> - One recent photograph (2 inches x 2 inches)
> - Appropriate visa fee (US $35)
> - Important: In order to be admitted into the country, tourists may need to demonstrate that they have sufficient funds for their stay and a return ticket.

**Must I have return or onward tickets when boarding to fly to Cambodia (Phnom Penh)? Or this is never checked by airlines (AirAsia) nor immigration?**

Comment: AirAsia can and does check.  Whether they will check you or not is simply the luck of the draw.

Comment: @pnuts Hi pnuts, just paid 39 USD for 3 tickets (my youngest is 5) https://catmekongexpress.com/booking.aspx cheaper when FlyOnward. Thanks.

Comment: @pnuts - there is no universally agreed upon POOT so airlines can set standards as they see fit to protect themselves. And sooner or later scams such as flyonward will be detectable and rejected as POOT.

Comment: @pnuts - Airlines have a legal responsibility to the government to make sure passengers they are transporting are eligible to enter that country.  They do not have a legal responsibility to assist you in meeting those requirements, that lies solely with the traveler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=KH&SECTION=vi&SUBSECTION=wa&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), the database used by airlines worldwide (**not** just KLM, despite the interface):

> Return/onward ticket is required for nationals of Afghanistan, Algeria, Bangladesh, Iran, Iraq, Pakistan,
>     Saudi Arabia, Sri Lanka and Sudan

Thus, as a Lithuanian, you don't need any proof of onward travel.

If you want to be safe, print out the linked extract.

Comment: I have crossed into Cambodia now multiple times by land and air (Phonm Penh) and can confirm that I haven't been or seen anyone being asked for proof of onward travel.